# Separate class declaration from definition

Tags: c++, class, declaration

I would like to separate class definition and declaration into 2 separate files: `foo.hpp` and `foo.inl`.

`foo.hpp` file has `Foo` class declaration with its' description, and also this file includes `foo.inl`:

```cpp
/* foo.hpp */

// Foo class description comment
class Foo;

#include "foo.inl"
```

`foo.inl` contains `Foo` definition without any code-description comments.

```cpp
/* foo.inl */

class Foo {
    Foo() = default;

    void bar() {
        /* do something */
    }
}
```

I am trying to write commentaries for `Foo`'s methods in `foo.hpp` to make it look like this:

```cpp
/* foo.hpp */

// Foo class description comment
class Foo;

// This is my default constructor
Foo::Foo();

// This is my very helpful function
Foo::bar();

#include "foo.inl"
```

But compiler gives an understandable error: `invalid use of incomplete type 'class Foo'`.

So is there any way how can I declare functions and write comments for them in such a way?

Comment: What is an `.inl` file? Where did this convention come from? This style really doesn't make any sense to me, and it bucks a lot of C++ conventions. Why not `.cpp` and `.hpp` (or `.h`) as is done the vast majority of C++ code bases?

Comment: `Foo::bar();` is a function call, not a function definition, and it is being called on what's just a forward declaration at that point, so it's not able to actually compile anything.

Comment: `.inl` file are used to separate template classes and functions declarations from definitions in `.hpp` file. So the `.hpp` file contains declarations and `.inl` file contains definitions.

Comment: In your example both declarations and definitions are in `foo.inl`. C++ does not allow any kind of separate declarations for class members.

Comment: Again, where did this convention come from? It's nothing I've ever seen before and it doesn't make any sense. What are the benefits here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Foo::Foo();` and `void Foo::bar();` area member function declarations, and those are not allowed outside of a class.

You have it a little bit backward, define the class in the "main" header file `foo.hpp`. Then define the functions as `inline` in the "inline" header file `foo.inl`.

Perhaps something like this:

```
// Foo.hpp
#pragma once

class Foo
{
public:
    // The default constructor
    Foo();

    // This is my very helpful function
    void bar();
};

#include "Foo.inl"
```

Then the inline file:

```
// Foo.inl
#pragma once

inline Foo::Foo()
{
}

inline void Foo::bar()
{
}
```

If the inline functions are simple enough, put them inside the `Foo` class definition in the main header file `Foo.hpp` instead. And if they're too complicated to really be inline, put them in a separate source file `Foo.cpp` to be built with your application (but *not* included with `#include`).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split definition and declaration of class methods, you have to define the class:

```
// .h

// That is my class Foo
class Foo {
    // Constructor
    Foo();

    // This is my very helpful function
    void bar();
};
```

and

```
// cpp
Foo::Foo() = default;

void Foo::bar() {
    /* do something */
}
```